# Which file contains the content of /customer/account/login

Tags: magento2

I want to change the content of this page: `/customer/account/login`

Which file in magento2 is responsible for the this page?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can Override  your **Magento-Customer** module

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml
```

keep your files in your **extended module** under this path and change your files, **if not present then create the folders and copy only required files**

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml
```

Thanks

Comment: thank you, in this file I only found the part where the login form is defined. Where can I find the part below the login form? I mean the register new customer text & button

Comment: vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/newcustomer.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Follow below directory and copy `login.phtml`

```
    vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml
```

Step 2. Paste login.phtml in below directory

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml
```